# How to remove leftmost/rightmost elements in list that satisfy a certain criterion in python?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

`['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '']`

This is the result of parsing a 'dirty' csv file. I now want to get rid of the empty columns on the right. I cannot just use counting, because the length is variable. I also cannot just use simple filtering, because there are also rows that look like this:

`['a1', '', 'c1', '', '']`

So I have to preserve the empty columns that are **not** at the very right. Is there an idiomatic way to do this? I am hoping for something like a "removeWhile" function that I could apply on the reversed list.

The best I've come up with so far is the following:

```
def filterRow(row):
    row.reverse()
    blanks = 0
    for x in row:
        if x == '':
            blanks += 1
        else:
            break
    row.reverse()
    return row[0:-blanks]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def filterRow(row):
    while row[-1] == "":
        row.pop()
```

If you don't want to do it in-place for some reason, do it like this instead:

```
def filterRow(row):
    row = list(row)
    while row[-1] == "":
        row.pop()
    return row
```

Popping off the end of a list is very fast, and though it *may* be slightly faster to calculate the last index and do a slice, it will also result in longer, more complicated, and harder to read code. Therefore, go with the readable version for now, and consider changing it only once you've determined it to be a significant bottleneck in practice.

To make the function even more intuitive, why not call it `rstrip` instead of `filterRow`, since it does almost the same thing that `str.rstrip` does to strings?

Comment: +1, very elegant. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16120252/1600898) demonstrates the slicing approach, but the index calculation ends up long, hard to understand, or both.

Comment: +1, but note that this breaks when all the columns are empty.

Comment: @root This is trivially fixed by changing the condition to `while row and row[-1] == ""`, but it would be a shame to clutter such an elegant solution — at least my hunch is that the OP's rows are never all-empty.

Answer (score 3):

While *@Lauritz V. Thaulow* has the cleanest soultion to your question, I think you may be asking the wrong question. Instead you should strip off the empty columns while you are reading the csv, not after you have already converted it to a list. Then a simple `line.rstrip(', \n')` should do.

```
In [1]: lst = ['a1', '', 'c1', '', '']

In [2]: def remove_while(lst):
   ...:     return ','.join(lst).rstrip(', ').split(',')

In [3]: remove_while(['a1', '', 'c1', '', ''])
Out[3]: ['a1', '', 'c1']
```

So you could just:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip(', \n').split(',')
#['a1', '', 'c1']
#['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it presumes a fixed CSV syntax. Despite the name, CSV supports many different field separators (Excel, at least in its European versions, defaults to `;` because `,` is the decimal separator in most European languages). Then there is the quoting, which can create different ways to represent an empty column. Unless you are generating the input CSV yourself, processing it should be left to the CSV reader.

Comment: @user4815162342 - this is just a toy example. Anyway you can still use the `csv.reader` with a generator like: `csv.reader(line.rstrip(', \n') for line in f)` - you would still have to specify the separator, but usually you know the format before reading the file.

Comment: But that's exactly the point - you often *don't* know the CSV dialect you'll encounter, the `csv` module autodetects it for you.

Comment: @user4815162342 -- when you use the sniffer you mean? I hardly ever see it used... But you are right, *if* you want to use autodetection, this is not suitable. Otherwise I would say it is both more efficient and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', '']
# iterate through the list in reverse...
>>> for v in l[::-1]:
        # when we encounter an element that's not empty, exit the loop
...     if v:
...         break
        # otherwise pop the last element off the end of the list
...     l.pop()

>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a succinct implementation using a single slice:

```
def filterRow(row):
    rightmost = next(i for i in reversed(xrange(len(row))) if row[i])
    del row[rightmost + 1:]
    # or, non-destructively: return row[:rightmost + 1]
```

Explanation:

- `reversed(xrange(len(row))` produces list indices in reverse order; the same as `xrange(len(row) - 1, -1, -1), but more readable.
- `i for i in INDICES if row[i]` is a generator expression that iterates over indices right-to-left, skipping empty ones.
- `next(iterable)` gets the first element of the generated expression. Applied to the above generator expression, it returns the index of the rightmost non-empty element.
- `del row[rightmost + 1:]` deletes all empty elements at the end of the row. (Alternatively, `return row[:rightmost + 1]` returns all elements up to and including the rightmost non-empty one.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, without creation of any new string, list or using reversed:

```
In [138]: def remove_while(lis):
   .....:     le=len(lis)
   .....:     ind=0
   .....:     for i in xrange(le-1,-1,-1):
   .....:         if lis[i]!="":
   .....:             break
   .....:         else:
   .....:             ind+=1
   .....:     del lis[-ind:]
   .....:     return lis
   .....: 

In [139]: remove_while(['a', 'b', 'c', '', '', ''])
Out[139]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [140]: remove_while(['a1', '', 'c1', '', ''])
Out[140]: ['a1', '', 'c1']

In [141]: remove_while(['', '', '', '', ''])
Out[141]: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but let it be here:

```
def strip(xs, predicate=lambda x: not x):
    """Given a sequence, remove leading/trailing items that match the predicate."""
    m = [bool(predicate(x)) for x in xs]
    try:
        a = m.index(False)
        b = m[::-1].index(False)
        return xs[a:len(xs)-b]
    except ValueError:
        return []


print strip(['','',1,2,'',3,4,0,None,'',''])        # [1, 2, '', 3, 4]
print strip([1,2,10,20,3,30,5,6], lambda x: x < 10) # [10, 20, 3, 30]
print strip([10,20,3,30], lambda x: x < 10)         # [10, 20, 3, 30]
print strip([1,2,3], lambda x: x < 10)              # []
```