# getting rid of some elements that contain just white space in a list

Tags: python, list

`['                      ','               ','                 ','       ', '12 21','12 34']`
I have a list like this, where the first few elements are any amount of white space. How can I remove the elements that contain just white space so the list becomes `['12 21', '12 34']`
The list is a lot larger than this I have just scaled it down, and the amount of elements that are just contain white space is not a fixed number.

Comment: `strip` function for lists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16120943/989121

Comment: I notice most people seem to interpret "How can I remove the elements..." as "How can I create a new list without the elements...", which isn't quite the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `str.strip()` and a simple list comprehension:

```
In [31]: lis=[' ',' ',' ',' ', '12 21','12 34']

In [32]: [x for x in lis if x.strip()]
Out[32]: ['12 21', '12 34']
```

or using `filter()`:

```
In [37]: filter(str.strip,lis)
Out[37]: ['12 21', '12 34']
```

This works because for empty strings:

```
In [35]: bool(" ".strip())
Out[35]: False
```

**help(str.strip)**:

```
In [36]: str.strip?
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'strip' of 'str' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode

Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`str.isspace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) method will return `True` if a string is entirely whitespace characters, so you can use the following:

```
lst = [x for x in lst if not x.isspace()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a large list, you may also want to consider using `itertools` so that you can ignore the whitespace only items instead of creating a new list:

```
>>> from itertools import ifilterfalse
>>> l = [' ',' ',' ',' ', '12 21','12 34']
>>> for item in ifilterfalse(str.isspace, l):
...     print item
... 
12 21
12 34
```

Comment: One minor (Python 2) downside of using `str.isspace` is that it'll complain if there are unicode strings in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I remove the elements that contain just white space so the list becomes `['12 21', '12 34']`

Given that the whitespace elements always occur at the start of the list, then...

If you need to modify the list in place, the most optimal solution would be something like this...

```
>>> l = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '12 21','12 34']
>>> while l[0].isspace(): del l[0]
>>> print l
['12 21', '12 34']
```

...or if you just want to iterate over the non-whitespace elements, then [`itertools.dropwhile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) would seem to be the most efficient method...

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '12 21','12 34']
>>> for i in itertools.dropwhile(str.isspace, l): print i
12 21
12 34
```

All of the other solutions will create a copy of the list and/or check every element, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "functional" way of doing this.

```
In [10]: a = [' ',' ',' ','12 24', '12 31']
In [11]: filter(str.strip, a)
Out[11]: ['12 24', '12 31']
```

This is the help on `filter`.

> Help on built-in function filter in module **builtin**:
>
> filter(...)
>      filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
>
> Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
>      function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
>      or string, return the same type, else return a list.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
a=['','',1,2,3]
b=[x for x in a if x <> '']
```

Comment: Downvote for using `<>`, and because `''` isnotaspaceasyoucantellfromthissentence.